# Controller test: ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError: ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fixtures

I try to test the controllers in my ruby on rails programm. However I get in every controller one of these errors:

```
Error:
ShoppingListsControllerTest#test_should_update_shopping_list:
ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError: ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError
```

Does somebody know why my syntax in fixtures are wrong? Here is an example how one of my fixtures look like:

**fixtures/shopping_lists:**

```
 shopping_list_drogerie:
  user: user_heiko
  name: Drogerie

 shopping_list_lebensmittel:
  user: user_schmitt
  name: Lebensmittel
```

**fixtures/users.yml**

```
user_heiko:
 firstname: Paul
 lastname: Heiko
 email: heiko@me.com
 encrypted_password: hhdk#s0
 description: Ich bin Heiko
 role: <%= User.roles[:senior] %>

user_schmitt:
 firstname: Lucia
 lastname: Schmitt
 email: schmitt@me.com
 encrypted_password: 9900837
 description: Ich bin Schmitt
 role: <%= User.roles[:senior] %>

user_shopper:
 firstname: Thomas
 lastname: Friedrich
 email: friedrich@me.com
 encrypted_password: *680831
 description: Ich bin der Shopper
 role: <%= User.roles[:shopper] %>
```

**shopping_lists_controller_test.rb**

```
  test "should update shopping_list" do
    login_as(@heiko)
    @heiko.confirmed_at = Time.now
    patch shopping_list_url(@drogerieShoppingList), params: { shopping_list: {name: 'WochenendEinkauf'  } }
    assert_redirected_to shopping_list_url(@drogerieShoppingList)
  end
```

Comment: are you using 1 space or 2 spaces? I was recommending 2 spaces. See my answer

Comment: hmm did not work neighter